# Print multiple sheets with different orientations

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing

I have a multisheet Excel Spreadsheet.

Some pages are setup as Portrait others are setup as Landscape.

Is there a way to define which pages should print as Portrait or Landscape, or is it an all one way or the other type of thing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `Page Setup` option you can determine orientation for each work sheet separately.

It will print the worksheets accordingly.

Comment: for each worksheet, select the range you need to print and set that as the print area for that sheet (in pre-2007 versions this is easier the other way round, now I come to think of it; Page Setup > Print area, use the range selection icon or just type in the box), set the orientation here too.
Unfortunately no way to do this for multiple sheets at once (grouping does not do it), but if you plan ahead and set up one sheet correctly, then copying that sheet will keep the properties the same

Comment: wow this is from 09 i don't even remember what this is for but i checked and it works so thanks