# How to set different orientation for different sheets in OpenOffice.org Calc?

Tags: printing, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc, landscape

I have document with two sheets sheet1 and sheet2 and i want set orientation of sheet1 to portrait and orientation of sheet2 to landscape.

This can be done in [Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/68063/print-multiple-sheets-with-different-orientations), but in OpenOffice when i set sheet1 to portrait and then sheet2 to landscape then both sheets are landscape.

How to do this in OpenOffice.org Calc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by assigning different **Sheet Styles** to the respective sheet.

To create a sheet style with landscape orientation:

1. Hit <kbd>F11</kbd> to open the "`Styles and Formatting`" window (it may be already visible and docked);

   [image]
2. Switch from "`Cell Style`" to "`Sheet Styles`";

   [image]
3. Right-click and select "`New`" (there's only this option);

   [image]
4. In the new Sheet Style properties, assign a name (for example, "`Landscape`"), and on the "`Page`" tab, set the Orientation to "`Landscape`";

   [image]
5. Hit <kbd>OK</kbd>. Now, there's your new sheet style in the sheet styles list.

   [image]
6. Select the sheet that should have landscape orientation, and double-click on the new page style entry in the "`Styles and Formatting`" window to apply it to the current sheet.

That's it.